# Sql injection while using @@TranCount instruction in SqlCommand

Tags: c#, t-sql, transactions, sql-injection, sqlcommand

I have such code:

```
private DbTransaction sqlTransaction = null;
...
...
...
using (DbCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT @@TRANCOUNT"))
{
   if ((int)command.ExecuteScalar() != 0) sqlTransaction.Rollback();
}
```

The problem is that I have an sql injection vulnerability in this part of code (according to veracode scanning). If I comment this row (which contains `ExecuteScalar()`) the vulnerability notification has gone...
Whats wrong with this code? Why it can be sql injection? And how should I change this code to prevent vulnerability?

Comment: I would argue there's nothing wrong with this code and Veracode is throwing a false positive.  Since there is no modification of the query text possible there is no possibility for injection.  My guess is that Veracode doesn't like the `@@`

Comment: There is definitely something wrong with this code, but it's not SQL injection, it's not knowing whether you are in a transaction and needing to check. Perhaps you need `SET XACT_ABORT ON;`